# Pagefile-backed memory-mapped files vs. Heap -- what's the difference?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, heap-memory, memory-mapped-files

What is the advantage of using a memory-mapped file backed by the system paging file (through `CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, ...)`, instead of just allocating memory from the heap the usual way (`malloc(...)`, `HeapAlloc(...)`, etc.)?

i.e. When should I use which?

Comment: Shared memory, the core of any IPC mechanism in Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's lower level, it gives you more than `malloc` does:

- You can share the mapping with other processes (of course you also need to synchronize)
- You can set permissions on the memory (for example you can have read-only memory via `PAGE_READONLY`)
- You can set some cache / page parameters

Comment: it should also avoid copying the file twice.